# How to stream audio/video from Raspberry Pi to Windows PC

Tags: pi-3, audio, video, streaming, rtl-sdr

I have a Raspberry Pi 3b that I am using as a radio server with a **rtl-sdr** (Realtec [Software Defined Radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio)).

I would like to have any audio coming from the Raspberry Pi to be streamed to my windows 10 PC in another room, wired network. Possibly a SDR server or something so I can also monitor the frequencies and such.

Comment: What is *rtl-sdr*?

Comment: SDR = Software Defined Radio (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio) and RTL = Realtec

Comment: http://thardes.de/raspberry-pi-als-sdr-server/ This tutorial is in german, but it might be helpful for you.